# Border missing in React-Native documentation?

Tags: react-native, text, border

I am new to React Native and wanted to create a text with border. Therefore I checked the docs at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text - the word "border" appears exactly zero times. However, border is available on `Text` and this works fine:

```
<Text style={{fontSize: 30, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'red'}}>Hello, world!</Text>
```

But where is this documented? Did I look at the wrong place? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is included under the style prop, there is a link to the inherited [View Style Props](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view-style-props#style) that include the border details that you are after.